# Angular 5 auth get token

Tags: angular5

I am working on Angular5 app user authentication, api return token on successful login. For some reasons LoginPageComponent has no idea what is the token, even if I store it in localstorage I will still get null.

What to do?

App Structure:
LoginPageComponent

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

import { AuthService } from '../../../shared/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.scss']
})

export class LoginPageComponent {

    @ViewChild('f') loginForm: NgForm;

    private user: any = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };

    constructor(
      private auth: AuthService,
      private router: Router,
      private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    // On submit button click
    onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
        this.auth.signinUser(f.value.email, f.value.password);

        // Returns even signinUser has token
        console.log(this.auth.getToken());
    }    
}
```

AuthService

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    this.userService.login(email, password).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.token = res.token;
      // here app has token and this.token contains value
    });
}

getToken() {
    return this.token;
}
```

UserService:

```
login(email, password) {
    this.endpoint = this.endpointLocal + '/api/auth/login';
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       this.http.post(this.endpoint, {"email": email, "password": password})
        .subscribe(res => resolve(res.json()));
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `signinUser` invokes asynchronous code, so the `then` portion of the Promise in `signinUser` won't have been executed before you make your console.log call in onSubmit.

If you modify your `signinUser` method in the `AuthService` to return the Promise, then you can just chain a `.then` call in your `LoginPageComponent.onSubmit` method:

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string): Promise {
    return this.userService.login(email, password).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.token = res.token;
      // here app has token and this.token contains value
    });
}

// On submit button click
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    this.auth.signinUser(f.value.email, f.value.password).then(() => {
        console.log(this.auth.getToken());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried but getting follow error when doing this.

signinUser(email: string, password: string): Promise {

Typescript Generic type 'Promise<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

Comment: Then add typing to match what you resolve the promise with, or just use `Promise<any>`